# Python Selenium Click Link by href

Tags: selenium, hyperlink

There are a lot of methods I've tried for clicking on the link generated by the HTML bellow

```
<a class="btn btn--primary welcomePageButton" href="#/dispatchlist">
  <span class="">View Dispatches/Invoices</span>
</a>
```

I've tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'dispatchlist')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("View Dispatches/Invoices").click()
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("View Dispatches").click()
```

And in every case, I got **NoSuchElementException**.

Can you please guide me to solve this?

PS: I used the latest version of Google Chrome.

Comment: You can try with `//a[.='View Dispatches/Invoices']`. You might have the element in the frame or you might need explicit wait using WebDriverWait to make sure the link is loaded by the time your try to click on it.

Comment: Your xpath is a working one ("//a[contains(@href,'dispatchlist')]"). You should be able to find the element with your xpath itself. You just have to take care of few points as @supputuri mentioned above. First, check if the element is inside a iframe. Second, add a appropriate wait for the element to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of xpaths, I decided to use JS snippets which worked like a charm

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].click()")
```

However, thanks, everyone.